# Permutations of a sequence, while keeping a pair of sub-sequences in order

Tags: combinatorics

If I have a word built from three different letters (r,g,b), for example

$r,g,r,g,b,b,r,b,b,g,g,r    \,\,\,(\text{Sequence A})$

how many permutations of this list preserve the order of the letters in the sub-sequence of b's and r's, and also, g's and b's?

So, in any permutation of the above sequence, the sub-sequence

$r,r,b,b,r,b,b,r     \,\,\,(\text{Sequence B})$

and

$g,g,b,b,b,b,g,g   \,\,\,(\text{Sequence C})$

must occur, in order. The r's  and g's however can be permuted as appropriate, so long as the other sequences are preserved. An example would be:

$r,r,g,g,b,b,r,b,b,g,g,r    \,\,\,(\text{Sequence D})$

where the first four letters are permuted.

In general, Sequence A is $(X_i)_{0 \leq i \leq n}$, where $X_i$ is uniform on the $m$ letters $\{1,2,\dots,m\}$, where we take $m=3$, and $n=12$ in this example.

Answer (score 1):

In your specific example: $r,g,r,g,b,b,r,b,b,g,g,r$, the permissible permutations would have the $b$'s in the same spots; and you can freely permute the $r$'s and $g$'s between any two $b$'s.  That is, a permissible sequence must have the form $[r,r,g,g],b,[r],b,b,[r,g,g]$ where you can permute the items within each bracket freely. The first bracket can be permuted in $6$ (distinguishable) ways; the second in $1$ way; and the third in $3$ ways. So for your example there are $18$ permissible permutations (including the original given sequence).

In general, the number of permutations of interest will depend on the unbroken contiguous subsequences of $r$'s and $g$'s.  For each such subsequence, if $n$ is the length of the subsequence and $k$ is the number of $r$'s, you will get a factor of ${n\choose k}$ in the answer.